# BottomBar overlays scaffold content when using LazyColumn

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

When I use `Scaffold` with a long `LazyColumn` in it's content and some composable in `bottomBar` parameter I can't see last item of the column because `BottomBar` overlays it. Is there a way to fix this overlaying?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your `Scaffold`, the `content` has a `PaddingValues` parameter, you can use it to add the correct padding.

Something like this:

```
Scaffold(
   ...
) {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(
                bottom = it.calculateBottomPadding()
            )
            //.padding(it) // <<-- or simply this 
    ) {
        // Your content
    }
}
```